# Unable to deploy Windows 8.1 App to Surface Pro 3 (DEP0700 Error)

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to deploy and test a Universal Windows App to a Surface Pro 3 directly from Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) and I am unable to launch the App (by hitting F5). I am running into the following error and not able to find a fix to it. There are a bunch of solutions of DEP0700 errors online, but none of them work for the specific sub-error message ***Cannot map the serial well-known device name to a device interface GUID (blah blah blah)***

Here is the error that I am seeing

```
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. c:\Builds\TestAppRT\AppX\AppxManifest.xml(38,6): error 0x80070002: 
Cannot map the serial well-known device name to a device interface GUID for the 11156705-8b60-4c7f-a75f-f8c7516401fc_1.0.0.0_neutral__1g7p71hbj7m7y package. 
Check that the device name is correct. (0x80073cf6)
```

Comment: The first time I ran into this issue, renaming the package name in the appxmanifest file fixed this issue. But I did not have luck with it the subsequent times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared any serial communication in your AppxManifest file?

If your other apps work, your issue might be because opening/editing ApxManifest file in the designer. Try making a new solution, and edit the manifest through only through XML Editor, if required & do not open with the designer.

Reference for more information:
http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm

"Visual Studio 2015 has a known bug in the Manifest Designer (the visual editor for appxmanifest files) that affects the serialcommunication capability.  If 
your appxmanifest adds the serialcommunication capability, modifying your appxmanifest with the designer will corrupt your appxmanifest (the Device xml child will be lost).  You can workaround this problem by hand editting the appxmanifest by right-clicking your appxmanifest and selecting View Code from the context menu."